# how to generate different html if the given object has no results

Tags: javascript

I am talking to WP REST API and if I do have results in data object I generate HTML code to frontend, and that is working fine, but what to do, and how to generate different HTML output (for example "There is no search result") if there is not data in data object.

I try with if statement but no luck with that. I am new to coding so forgive me if this is trivial problem...

```js
var searchVal = this.inputField.val();
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8888/wptest/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=' + searchVal,
  data => {
    this.createHtml.html(`
            <h2 class="search-overlay__section-title">Posts Info</h2> 
            <ul class="link-list min-list">
            <li><a href="${data[0].link}">${data[0].title.rendered}</a></li>
            </ul>
            `);

  });
```

Comment: Why doesnt `if` work, can you share your code in which you tried with `if`

Comment: `if(data.length == 0){ // no results }else{ //results }`

Comment: What happens when this is done ? It should work if you have kept it inside that anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks guys I will try this now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work if its as below:

```
var searchVal = this.inputField.val();
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8888/wptest/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=' + searchVal,
  data => {
    if (data.length == 0) {
     // no results html
    } else {
    this.createHtml.html(`
            <h2 class="search-overlay__section-title">Posts Info</h2> 
            <ul class="link-list min-list">
            <li><a href="${data[0].link}">${data[0].title.rendered}</a></li>
            </ul>
            `);
    }

  });
```

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys I did a little research and found a more concise solution, Ternary Operator... sorry if I didn't say it was ES6 syntax and I used a compiler to run regular javascript in the browser

```
var searchVal = this.inputField.val();
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8888/wptest/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=' + searchVal,
        data => {
            this.createHtml.html(`
                <h2 class="search-overlay__section-title">Posts Info</h2> 
                ${data.length == 0 ? '<p>No Results</p>' : '<ul class="link-list min-list">'}
                ${data.map(item => `<li><a href="${item.link}">${item.title.rendered}</a></li>`).join('')}
                ${data.length == 0 ? '</ul>' : ''}
            `);
        });
```